# How do I create a function in R that returns where my matrix is not symmetric?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I can't lie, I'm on a pretty big time crunch. I'm trying to make a function that takes a matrix as input and checks if this matrix is symmetric. If this matrix is indeed symmetric, nothing happens -- it spits out, "Your input matrix is symmetric." However, if the input matrix is *not symmetric*, the function then combs through the entire matrix and searches for which entries don't match. I'd love it to return something like, "Entry [4,5] does not equal entry [5,4]" or if there are multiple entries that are not equal, it would just print a big list of statements like the one above. Here is what I have so far:

```
SymmetricErrorFinder <- function(matrix){
  if(isSymmetric(matrix) == TRUE){
    print("Your input matrix is symmetric!")
  }else{
    for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)){
      for (j in 1:ncol(matrix)){
        if(matrix[i,j] != matrix[j,i]){
          return(cat("The entry that needs correcting is", matrix[i,j]))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem with this is that when it returns `matrix[i,j`, it will return a specific number, not the index of the entry, if you will. See what I mean? I'm sorry if it isn't clear. I also can't figure out how to get it to say "Entry[i,j] does not equal entry [j,i]" but if that's impossible what I have written in the code block above will absolutely work too since what I'm trying to create is a symmetric matrix after all. Please and thank you of course!

Edit: I'll add some context if it helps. This is not a final exam question nor a homework assignment problem or anything. I'm working on a big final project and I've created a matrix that is 130 rows by 130 columns. I'll save you the math, that's 16,900 entries. It's all either 1's or 0's. Specifically the diagonals are supposed to be 0 (I should probably add that into my function somehow...). I need this matrix to be symmetric. When I read in my data I had created and checked if it was symmetric using the `isSymmetric()` function, it came back `FALSE`. I do not have the time to hunt through all this to try and find where the inconsistency is at. Hence the need for this function. I don't think there will be many inconsistencies mind you, but because there are so many entries I really am searching for some needles in a haystack.

More context: I'm trying to build an affiliation network of a bunch of MCU characters. I've got 130 of them (and that's with me excluding a few!) and so even though this adjacency matrix is rather sparse, hunting for where the matrix entries don't line up is a task. I also can't just set the non-equal entries to 0 because say, if the [Tony Stark, Pepper Potts] entry is a 1 but the [Pepper Potts, Tony Stark] entry is a 0, that's blatantly false and when I try to graph this using the iGraph package I'd be missing out on some important data and it would also be wrong.

Comment: Reading the details of your use-case, if you want to make your binary matrix `m` symmetric by assuming that all 1s are correct and the errors are that some 0s should be 1s based on symmetry, you could do, e.g., `m_symm = m | t(m); mode(m_symm) = "integer"`

Answer (score 4):

```
asymm = matrix(c(
    1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1,
    3, 1, 1
  ), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

symm = matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

asymm_index = function(m) {
  which(m != t(m), arr.ind = TRUE)
}

asymm_index(asymm)
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   3   1
# [3,]   1   2
# [4,]   1   3

asymm_index(symm)
#     row col
```

You could, of course, do special handling to check if the result has rows - if no rows, then the matrix is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

How about you check if the matrix is equal to its transpose and then look for FALSE values?

Example:

```
mat2 <- diag(5)
mat3 <- mat2
mat3[1, 2] <- 4


isSymmetric(mat2)

fIsSymm <- function(x) {
  x  == t(x)
}

> fIsSymm(mat2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> fIsSymm(mat3)
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: `which(x != t(x))` will be more useful on a big matrix, see the answer by Gregor Thomas.